# Generate route in twig template

Tags: symfony, twig

I need to generate route in twig, which look like

trololo.com/#apple

I try do like this

```
{{ path('productsAction', {'#' : product.slug}) }}
```

In result i have `trololo.com/?%=apple
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What does your actual routing.yml look like where you define `productsAction` path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like 
`<a href="{{ path('productsAction') ~ '/#' ~ product.slug }}">Apple</a>`

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
{{ path('productsAction') }}#{{ product.slug }}
```